# Python 3 virtualenv and Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to build a docker image with python 3 and virtualenv.
I understand that I wouldn't need to use wirtualenv in a docker image as I'm going to use only python 3, yet I see some clean isolation benefits of using virtualenv anyways.

What's the best practice? Should I avoid using virtualenv on docker?
If that's the case, how can I setup python3 and pip3 to be used as python and pip (without the 3)?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash gcc musl-dev
RUN apk add python3 python3-dev
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN apk add libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

ENV PROJECT_HOME /opt/app

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/modules

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jep
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so

RUN pip3 install jep
RUN pip3 install ads
RUN pip3 install gspread
RUN pip3 list

COPY target/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $PROJECT_HOME/my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME

CMD ["java", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my-mongo:27017/mydb","-jar","./my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Thanks

**=== UPDATE 1 ===**
I'm trying to create a new virtual env in the WORKDIR, install some libs and then execute a shell script, even though I see it creates the whole thing when I build the image, when running the container the environment folder is empty.

This is from my Dockerfile:

```
RUN virtualenv ./env && source ./env/bin/activate && pip install jep \
    googleads gspread oauth2client

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ./env/bin/activate
java -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my-mongo:27017/mydb -jar ./my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It builds fine but on docker-compose up -d this is the output:

```
./startup.sh: source: line 2: can't open './env/bin/activate'
```

The env folder exists, but it's **empty**.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**=== UPDATE 2 ===**
This is the working config:

```
RUN virtualenv ./my-env && source ./my-env/bin/activate \
    && pip install gspread==0.6.2 jep oauth2client googleads pandas

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./startup.sh"]
```

This is startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
source ./my-env/bin/activate
java -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my-mongo:27017/mydb -jar ./my-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Edit the `PATH` variable to include the location of the `python3` installation and then symbolically link `python3` and `pip3` to `python` and `pip`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using virtualenv in docker is something really negative, it will slow down your container builds just a bit.

As for renaming pip3 and python3, you can create a hard link like this:

```
ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

assuming python3 executable is in /usr/bin/. You can find its location by running `which python3`

P.S.: Your dockerfile contains loads of `RUN` instructions, that are creating unnecessary intermediate containers. Combine them to save space and time:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash gcc musl-dev \
    python3 python3-dev py3-pip \
    libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/modules # you don't need the first one, -p will create it for you

RUN pip3 install jep ads gspread
```

Or combine them even further, if you aren't planning to change them often:

```
RUN apk update
 && apk add bash gcc musl-dev    \
    python3 python3-dev py3-pip  \
    libxslt-dev libxml2-dev      \
 && mkdir -p /opt/app/modules    \
 && pip3 install jep ads gspread
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the tips, good ones!
Now, in the case I want to indeed use virtualenv, what's the right way to activate it in Dockerfile and have access to it from the last CMD?  
Eventually if I enter to the container via ssh I'd need it activated also.

I tried the normal way and It's not activated (from its startup) if I open the terminal, like if it were a different terminal/ tty. Should I use a bash script for activating it and running the jar?

Comment: Well, if your activate the environment and perform actions inside one RUN block then everything should work normally. Use && and \

Comment: I can activate the environment from inside a RUN block but I cannot start the java jar application but in a CMD at the end, when the container starts. 
And I need my java app to get run under the virtualenv activated,  Any suggestion?

Comment: Create entrypoint.sh script that both activates virtual env and launches the java app, COPY it inside the container and put it in the CMD. Don’t forget to `chmod +x` it on your local machine.

Comment: Please take a look at UPDATE 1 in the question. I'm creating the virtualenv at build time but when running the CMD at the end it cannot see the env directory; thus It cannot activate it.

Comment: Btw I thought I could actually build my env locally and just COPY the folder to the docker image, but it also didn't work

Comment: @magnoz I suspect you are working in different directories. Add `echo "$PWD"` to the RUN block (`virtualenv ./env && echo "$PWD" && ...`)  and to your `startup.sh` and compare...

Comment: I actually did that and the path is ok. Now I entered via ssh also and I see the "env" folder but there is nothing on it. However at build time I see that virtualenv installs pip and all the stuff....

Comment: It might be that RUN creates another image/layer on which installs the virtualenv, then when CMD or ENTRYPOINT executes my startup script doesn't see anything... (?)

Comment: **At build time**: `New python executable in /opt/app/env/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /opt/app/env/bin/python`. **At run time**: /opt/app/env is __empty__

Comment: I followed your recommendations and your example and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only "workaround" I've found in order to use virtualenv from my docker container is to enter to the docker by ssh, create the environment, install the libs and set its folder as a volume in the docker-compose config so it won't be deleted and I can use it afterward.

(Or to have it ready and just copy the folder at build time) which could be a good option for saving build time, isn't it?

Otherwise, If I create it on Dockerfile and install the libs there, its folder gets empty when the container runs. Don't know why.

I appreciate if anyone can suggest a better way to deal with that.

Comment: Would you mind joining me in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173391/room-for-magnoz-and-andrew-morozko I can't replicate this behaviour...